# Method to speed up a VLOOKUP on two CSV files created from spreadsheet data

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

First I need to `VLOOKUP` twice in a CSV to find the name of the two teams, then I join the two names and do another VLOOKUP in another CSV:

```
function duoble_vlookup() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var search_values = s.getRange("Import_Data!K2:K3").getValues();

  var teams_url = 'url csv 1';
  var teams_csv = Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(teams_url));
  
  var match_col = teams_csv.map(row => row[0]);
  var match_list = match_col.join("ღ").split("ღ");

  var index = match_list.indexOf(search_values[0][0]);
  if (index === -1) {
    var team_home = 'off';
  } else {
    var row = index;
    var found_value = teams_csv[row][1];
    var team_home = found_value;
  }
  
  var index = match_list.indexOf(search_values[1][0]);
  if (index === -1) {
    var team_away = 'off';
  } else {
    var row = index;
    var found_value = teams_csv[row][1];
    var team_away = found_value;
  }
  
  var match_name = team_home + ' v ' + team_away;
  
  var all_values_csv_url = 'url csv 2';
  var all_values_csv = Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(all_values_csv_url));
  var match_col = all_values_csv.map(row => row[2]);
  var match_list = match_col.join("ღ").split("ღ");
  var index = match_list.indexOf(match_name);
  if (index === -1) {
    s.getRange("Gerais!B420:F420").setValues([['-','-','-','-','-']]);
  } else {
    var row = index;
    var found_value = [[all_values_csv[row][5],all_values_csv[row][6],all_values_csv[row][7],all_values_csv[row][8],all_values_csv[row][9]]];
    s.getRange("Gerais!B420:F420").setValues(found_value);
  }
}
```

This work takes between 28 to 45 seconds to be done, is there any method more agile than it for this or is this really the reality of this case?

For example to tests:

`Import_Data!K2:K3`:

```
/95/
/117/
```

Result in `Gerais!B420:F420`:

| B420 | C420 | D420 | E420 | F420 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4.5 | 3.45 | 1.95 | 2.02 |

Comment: Can you provide the sample input CSV data and the sample output situation you expect?

Comment: By the way, I think that `var match_col = teams_csv.map(row => row[0]);` and `var match_list = match_col.join("ღ").split("ღ");` are the same. Can I ask you about your expected result here?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike Yes, I can do that, I'll edit the content to hide what can't be shared and send the links to help you see!

Comment: @Tanaike The idea at this point of the code is just to generate a single list for the index search, I believe that both are really doing the same job, I just noticed with you commenting!

Comment: Hi @Tanaike csv's included in the question and sample test data also included, note that sometimes when I run this script more than once with the same values, it sometimes runs in less than 10 seconds, but that's not the normal in my trigger that runs every 30 minutes, it takes much longer than that when you need to do new research..

Comment: Thank you for replying. By guessing your situation, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize. At that time, I thought that it might be required to test the script using a sample CSV data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

#### Modification points:

- When the ternary operator instead of the if statement is used, the process cost can be reduced a little. [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/07/11/benchmark-conditional-branch-using-google-apps-script/)
- As I mentioned in my comment, in your script, `var match_col = teams_csv.map(row => row[0]);` and `var match_list = match_col.join("ღ").split("ღ");` are the same result.
- I thought that when `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll` insted of `UrlFetchApp.fetch` is used, the process cost can be reduced a little. [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/04/19/benchmark-fetchall-method-in-urlfetch-service-for-google-apps-script/)

When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function duoble_vlookup() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var search_values = s.getRange("Import_Data!K2:K3").getValues();

  var teams_url = 'url csv 1';
  var all_values_csv_url = 'url csv 2';
  var [teams_csv, all_values_csv] = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll([teams_url, all_values_csv_url]).map(r => Utilities.parseCsv(r.getContentText()));

  var match_col1 = teams_csv.map(row => row[0]);
  var index1 = match_col1.indexOf(search_values[0][0]);
  var index2 = match_col1.indexOf(search_values[1][0]);
  var team_home = index1 === -1 ? 'off' : teams_csv[index1][1];
  var team_away = index2 === -1 ? 'off' : teams_csv[index2][1];
  var match_name = team_home + ' v ' + team_away;

  var match_col2 = all_values_csv.map(row => row[2]);
  var index = match_col2.indexOf(match_name);
  var values = index === -1 ? [['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']] : [[all_values_csv[index][5], all_values_csv[index][6], all_values_csv[index][7], all_values_csv[index][8], all_values_csv[index][9]]];
  s.getRange("Gerais!B420:F420").setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- I'm not sure about your actual CSV data. So, when this modification was not useful, I thought that it might be required to test the script using a sample CSV data.

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Conditional Branch using Google Apps Script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/07/11/benchmark-conditional-branch-using-google-apps-script/)
- [Benchmark: fetchAll method in UrlFetch service for Google Apps Script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/04/19/benchmark-fetchall-method-in-urlfetch-service-for-google-apps-script/)

Comment: Its generate a error like: ```Exception: invalid argument (line 7)``` the line 7 is ```var [teams_csv, all_values_csv] =  ...```, is it the fetchAll method?

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. I have to apologize. I miscopied the script. It's `var [teams_csv, all_values_csv] = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll([teams_url, all_values_csv_url]).map(r => Utilities.parseCsv(r.getContentText()));`. Please test it again.

Comment: I'll let it run in my trigger but I've already noticed a huge difference in the response → 2,013 seconds total run, 2 seconds vs 45 seconds, huge difference!

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.